# EF Core using HasConversion to save custom string not working

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to follow along the Hands-On RESTful Web Services with ASP.NET Core 3 examples but I am getting an error when I try to do a migration based off the item entity schema definition. Its coming from the code with HasConversion. Here is the schema definition code in the book:

```
public class ItemEntitySchemaDefinition : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Item> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Items", CatalogContext.DEFAULT_SCHEMA);
            builder.HasKey(key=>key.Id);

            builder.Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Description).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(1000);

            builder.HasOne(p => p.Genre).WithMany(c => c.Items).HasForeignKey(k => k.GenreId);

            builder.HasOne(p => p.Artist).WithMany(c => c.Items).HasForeignKey(k => k.ArtistId);
             
            builder.Property(x => x.Price).HasConversion(
                p => $"{p.Amount}:{p.Currency}",
                p => new Price
                {
                    Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(p.Split(":", StringSplitOptions.None)[0]),
                    Currency = p.Split(":", StringSplitOptions.None)[1]
                });
        }
    }
```

Here is the Item and the Price Entity:

```
public class Item
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string LabelName { get; set; }
        public Price Price { get; set; }
        public string PictureUri { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public int AvailableStock { get; set; }
        public Guid GenreId { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre  {get;set;}
        public Guid ArtistId { get; set; }
        public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }

public class Price
    { 
        public decimal Amount {get;set;}
        public string Currency {get;set;}
    }
```

Its saying that it needs a primary key. However, this entity is not mapped to the DB so I dont understand why it would need a primary key. I tried adding a key but it gave another error. So I figure I would ask how to get this working without an Id.

Comment: try adding [NotMapped] attribute to Price entity.

Comment: Perfect! That worked. Thank you!